# Avoid 'interleaved LSN' in postgres replication slot

Tags: postgresql, wal, logical-replication

I am trying to stream data from postgres replication slot with output plugin 'test_decoding'. When there are big, multiple transactions running, the output plugin seems to have interleaved LSN, ie, they are not in sequence.

How can I have the transactions in sequence and if that's not possible, how can I keep track of the offset, ie, up till where I have read and I will use this offset as starting point to stream data.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you mean?  Maybe using `pg_recvlogical  -v` to test it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I need this because I am working on a generic app to replicate data from any postgres source

Comment: Yes, but why is a certain sequence of log sequence numbers important for you?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I will be storing the offset up till where I have read from the slot and the next time, I stream, I will use this offset as starting point